Partial fraction expansions of meromorphic functions
Sorry if this question (inspired by the recent flurry of activity around a "new" formula for $\pi$) is too naive.
Imitating what one does with Hadamard products, one can try to do the same with sums.
Consider $\Gamma(x)$. It has poles at $0$, $-1$,... with known residues, so we can write
$$\Gamma(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!(x+n)}+f(x)\;,$$
where $f(x)$ is an entire function. $f$ cannot be $0$ (for instance make $x\to\infty$), and we readily find that $f(x)=\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$. Good.
Now let's do the same with the beta function $B(x,y)=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)/\Gamma(x+y)$ considering $y$ as a fixed parameter. One finds that
$$\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{(1-y)_n}{n!(x+n)}+g(x,y)$$
for some function $g(x,y)$ which has no more poles in $x$, where $(a)_n$ is the (rising) Pochhammer symbol. For $x$, $y$ real the series converges only for $y>0$ I believe. Is there a "trivial" way to see that $g(x,y)$ is identically $0$ (if it is indeed $0$) ?

You can start from the partial fraction expansion of $(x+y)n/(x){n+1}$ and then let $n\rightarrow\infty$. In hypergeometric terms, you start from a special case of the terminating Saalschütz ${}_3F_2$-summation and obtain a special case of the Gauss ${}_2F_1$-summation in the limit. This is the method I use here. But I guess you ask for something where you start from the infinite series.

Liouville's theorem?

@Nemo What is obvious is that for fixed $y>0$, $g(x,y)$ is bounded if $x$ avoids the negative half-line (I guess more precisely in $|\arg(x)|<\pi-\delta$ for any $\delta>0$). The problem is to study $g(x,y)$ for large negative $x$. It vanishes at the negative integers but conceivably there could be some oscillations between them. I guess the question is to give a direct proof that this is not the case. In any case, the identity $g(x,y)\equiv 0$ is a special case of Gauss' summation.
